# Image translation using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I want to perform image translation by a certain amount (shift the image vertically and horizontally).

The problem is that when I paste the cropped image back on the canvas, I just get back a white blank box.

Can anyone spot the issue here?

Many thanks

```
img_shape = image.shape

# translate image
# percentage of the dimension of the image to translate
translate_factor_x = random.uniform(*translate)
translate_factor_y = random.uniform(*translate)

# initialize a black image the same size as the image
canvas = np.zeros(img_shape)

# get the top-left corner coordinates of the shifted image
corner_x = int(translate_factor_x*img_shape[1])
corner_y = int(translate_factor_y*img_shape[0])

# determine which part of the image will be pasted
mask = image[max(-corner_y, 0):min(img_shape[0], -corner_y + img_shape[0]),
             max(-corner_x, 0):min(img_shape[1], -corner_x + img_shape[1]),
             :]

# determine which part of the canvas the image will be pasted on
target_coords =  [max(0,corner_y),
                    max(corner_x,0),
                    min(img_shape[0], corner_y + img_shape[0]),
                    min(img_shape[1],corner_x + img_shape[1])]

# paste image on selected part of the canvas
canvas[target_coords[0]:target_coords[2], target_coords[1]:target_coords[3],:] = mask
transformed_img = canvas

plt.imshow(transformed_img)
```

This is what I get:

[image]

Comment: I just spotted that yellow dot on the white space, which I also don't know what it is!!

Comment: Why don't you just do numpy slicing to crop some part (x2,y2,w,h) of the image and then just insert it using numpy into your black background image at (x1,y1,w,h)? `canvas[y1:y1+h, x1:x1+w] = image[y2:y2+h, x2:x2+w]` The translation amount is (x1-x2) and (y1-y2).

Comment: Can you provide us with the original image? Thank you. I suspect it is most likely datatype issue. But unless you provide us with reproducible code, it is hard to find the issue.

Comment: use `numpy.pad`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For image translation, you can make use of the somewhat obscure `numpy.roll` function. In this example I'm going to use a white canvas so it is easier to visualize.

```py
image = np.full_like(original_image, 255)
height, width = image.shape[:-1]
shift = 100

# shift image
rolled = np.roll(image, shift, axis=[0, 1])
# black out shifted parts
rolled = cv2.rectangle(rolled, (0, 0), (width, shift), 0, -1)
rolled = cv2.rectangle(rolled, (0, 0), (shift, height), 0, -1)
```

If you want to flip the image so the black part is on the other side, you can use both `np.fliplr` and `np.flipud`.

Result:
[image: shifted image]

Comment: This will work if I black out the rolled over parts, but there must be a better way of doing it without using if statement, as I did: `# black out the shifted parts
if h_shift < 0:
    new_img[:, h_shift:] = 0
else:
    new_img[:, :h_shift] = 0
    
if v_shift < 0:
    new_img[v_shift:, :] = 0
else:
    new_img[:v_shift, :] = 0
`

Comment: I don't think I follow; do you want to black out the shifted parts?

Comment: So basically the image in the original post is what I want, where the white part should be the shifted image.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution that translates an image by `tx` and `ty` pixels using only array indexing, that does not roll over, and handles negative values as well:

```py
tx, ty = 8, 5  # translation on x and y axis, in pixels
N, M = image.shape
image_translated = np.zeros_like(image)

image_translated[max(tx,0):M+min(tx,0), max(ty,0):N+min(ty,0)] = image[-min(tx,0):M-max(tx,0), -min(ty,0):N-max(ty,0)]
```

Example:

[image]

(Note that for simplicity it does not handle cases where `tx > M` or `ty > N`).