# Translate a quantized (2D) image with numpy.roll()

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

I'm working on image processing of moles for a university project and I want to create a flipped copy of a quantized image. The problem is that I can't translate the image. I need to translate it so that the center of the mole coincides with the center of the image. I tried to use the numpy roll function as suggested here:

[Image translation using numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63367506/image-translation-using-numpy)

but it returns me this error:

```
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

and I don't know what it causes it. I also found a PIL function, Image.AFFINE, but I don't know how to use it to shift the image of the wanted delta.
The following image is the one I want to translate. The blue cross identifies the center of the image, while the red one identifies the centroid of the yellow region.

P.S. If possible, I would like to avoid Opencv
[image]

Comment: By carrying out several tests, I found out that the problem is that the delta is negative. Is there a way to translate the image of a negative shift?

Answer (score 0):

The reason of the error was the negative value of the shift.

I found another function: shift() from the library scipy and it seems to work